# why bashdb step+ command not found?

Tags: bash, debug

Ubuntu 20.04.6
bash debugger, bashdb, release 4.2-0.8

When I used `step+` command, 'not found' occured.

```
/usr/share/bashdb/lib/processor.sh: line 286: _Dbg_do_step-: command not found
```

`step` works fine.